# How to get anothers host IP based on variables?

Tags: ansible

I'd like to get the IP of a given host within my inventory based on the variables it has.

**hosts**

```
[pgsql_servers]
psql-01 ansible_host=10.11.12.13  pg_master=True  pg_slave=False
psql-02 ansible_host=10.11.12.14  pg_master=False pg_slave=True
psql-03 ansible_host=10.11.12.15  pg_master=False pg_slave=True

[pgsql_servers:vars]
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3
```

So within my slave-tasks, which only run for slaves, I'd like to get the IP of the only master given.

**slave-tasks.yml**

```
- name: Replicate data from Master
  command: repmgr -h HOW_TO_GET_MASTER-IP_HERE -U repmgr -d repmgr -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main -f /etc/repmgr.conf standby clone
  become: true
  become_user: postgres
```

I thought of adding a `when` here, but the master won't hit the `slave-tasks.yml` so it'll never become `True`. Any ideas of how to manage this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fetch master without defining extra variable (which is prone to copy-pasting errors):

```
- name: Replicate data from Master
  command: repmgr -h {{ master_ip }} -U repmgr -d repmgr -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main -f /etc/repmgr.conf standby clone
  become: true
  become_user: postgres
  vars:
    master_ip: "{{ hostvars | json_query('* | [?pg_master] | [0].ansible_host') }}"
```

json_query explained:

```
* - take all values of current dictionary as a list
[?pg_master] - select only elements that evaluate pg_master key as true
[0].ansible_host - select ansible_host of the first element
```

Comment: didn't knew until now json_querys are even possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It’s simple. Just add another variable to your `hosts` like `pg_master_ip` with the IP of the master and use it in your `slave-tasks.yml` like

```
- name: Replicate data from Master
  command: repmgr -h {{ pg_master_ip }} -U repmgr -d repmgr -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main -f /etc/repmgr.conf standby clone
  become: true
  become_user: postgres
```